# Queing notification in PHP using AJAX with beep sound

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am building now a Queuing system for my helpdesk system. i have problem in detecting the changes of input value. I want to play the play_sound() function sound when the value of input is incremented. the curent value of input is coming from the rowCount in my SQL Query stored in variable.
[screenshot picture link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibCvb.png)

**Input**

```
  <input disabled type="text" id="needapproval"  id="approval" value="0" class="center" />
```

**My Script**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function play_sound() {
    var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'Kalimba.mp3');
    audioElement.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
    audioElement.load();
    audioElement.play();
  }
  activateMagic();
  function activateMagic() {
    setInterval(realTimeData, 1000);
        function realTimeData() {
            $.ajax({
                url: './includes/needapproval.php',
                method: 'GET',
                  dataType: "json",
                success: function(res) {
                    $("#needapproval").val(res.data_count);
                },
                error: function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        }
    }
   </script>
```

**PHP**

```
require_once "connection.php";
    class NeedApprovalStatus extends Connection{
            public function needApproval() {
              $count_approval = "SELECT * FROM job_request WHERE approval_status LIKE '%Need Approval%' ";
              $stmt_count_approval = $this->db->prepare($count_approval);
              $stmt_count_approval->execute();
              $count = $stmt_count_approval->rowCount();
              $data_count = [];
                if ($count == 0) {
                    $data_count = [
                          'data_count'  => 0
                      ];
                } else {
                    $data_count = [
                          'data_count' => $count
                      ];
                }
                  echo json_encode($data_count);
            }

   }
    $need_approval = new NeedApprovalStatus;
    $need_approval->needApproval();
```

I tried to use onchange event in jquery but it doesn't work. because i think onchange only trigger when you change value on input manually. Any ideas guys?

Comment: Store previous count in  variable and check every time ajax succeeds if it changed. If it did... ring the bell and update variable

Comment: How i do check if the value is changed? i want to play the bell sound if the value is incremented only.

Comment: to check if it's changed...compare the new variable value with the old one which you stored.

Comment: Okay i will try it. And give you a feedback. Thanks

Comment: I cant identify the current value with the old value guys because of my setInterval()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to check the value inside the `success` function and call `play_sound()` from there.

```
function activateMagic() {

    var value = 0;

    setInterval(realTimeData, 1000);
    function realTimeData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: './includes/needapproval.php',
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(res) {
                var newValue = res.data_count;

                if(newValue != value) {
                    play_sound()
                    $("#needapproval").val(value);
                    value = newValue;
                }
            }
         ...
```

Comment: the sound play continously, it doesnt stop. i want it to play if the value is incremented only.

Comment: This is not going to stop the sound once it is started. How long is the audio clip? How long do you want it to play for?

Comment: You could always add a `stop_play()` function, set a delay and then call `stop_play()`

Comment: the sound is looping sir. the sound is only 5 secs. but it plays continously it doesnt stop.

Comment: where i put that?

Comment: try adding `audioElement.setAttribute('loop', false);` to your js

Comment: might need to be `audioElement.setAttribute('loop', 'false');`

Comment: If not that, check to see what `newValue` and `value` are every time the function fires

Comment: You can use the debugger to do this or you can run `console.log('new: ', newValue, ' old: ', value);` inside the `success` function just after you set the value of `newValue`

Comment: the value of variable value  must not 0. it must the res.data_count. the default value of input is 0. it changes in success: of ajax

Comment: The first time the script runs `value` is 0. When the `ajax` returns it checks if the `newValue` equals 0. If not then it should be updating `value` and run again checking against the new `value`.

Comment: make sure  `var value = 0` is outside of the `realTimeData()` function

Comment: the sound loops countinous because newValue != value condition is always try. because the value variable  is always 0. i want to detect the value of input is incremented and play the sound once.

Comment: `value` should not always `= 0`. I think you are setting it to `0` inside the `realTimeData()` function

Comment: No im not sir the var value is outside the realTimeData()

Comment: Check this out, open your dev console to see the output: https://jsfiddle.net/771k6xha/